# How do you replace the current parent serial number as the current serial number to be searched?

Tags: serialization, bots

When I created the program, my goal is to hopefully locate the original bot that has 0 as it's serial number using a loop process and random integers.

Here's the code for the random integers:

```
    private Random Bot SN = new Random(); // Serial number randomizer    

    // Bot serial number
    private int botSerialNumber = SN.nextInt(rangeSerialNumber); // Sets the bot's serial number

    public int getSN() { // A getter for the bot's serial number
        return this.botSerialNumber;
    }

    // Bot parent number
    private int parentSerialNumber = SN.nextInt(rangeSerialNumber); // Sets the bot's parent number

    public int getParentSN() { // A getter for the bot's serial number
        return this.parentSerialNumber;
    }

    public void setNewBotSN(int botSerialNumber) { // Sets the new bot parent number as the serial number        
    this.botSerialNumber = botSerialNumber;
    }
```

The loop process goes like this:

```
int botCounter = 0;
int botPopulation = 1000;

while (botCounter < botPopulation) { // Loop
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1); // Delay
            Bot bot = new Bot(); // Creates new bot
            if (bot.getSN() == bot.originalSN) { // Main Code
                System.out.println("Bot found!");
                break;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Current bot serial number does not match");
                bot.setNewBotSN(bot.getParentSN()); // Changes the the serial number to parent number
                System.out.println("New bot serial number is " + bot.getSN());
                System.out.println();
                botCounter++;
            }
        }
```

In actual, results it should look like this:

```
Bot serial number: 124
Bot parent number: 67

Current bot serial number does not match
New bot serial number is 67

Bot serial number: 67 // It then uses the previous parent number as the current serial number
Bot parent number: 0

Current bot serial number does not match
New bot serial number is 0

Bot serial number: 0
Bot parent serial number: <any number> // Because we have found the bot that has 0 as its serial number

Bot found!
```

The error is that whenever it iterates through the loop, the parent number set as the serial number gets changed to another new serial number.

```
Bot serial number 151
Bot parent number 200

Current bot serial number does not match
New bot serial number is 200 // It correctly changed the serial number to parent number

Bot serial number 523 // Then it changes that to another serial number
Bot parent number 377

Current bot serial number does not match
New bot serial number is 377

Bot serial number 920
Bot parent number 635
```

Is there anything wrong with my code?

Entire code:

```
package com.missingVariable.Application;

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

class Bot { // I created a class 
    public final int originalSN = 0; // Original serial number to be searched

    private final int rangeSerialNumber = 1000;

    private Random SN = new Random(); // Serial number randomizer
    
    // Bot serial number
    private int botSerialNumber = SN.nextInt(rangeSerialNumber); // Sets the bot's serial number

    public int getSN() { // A getter for the bot's serial number
        return this.botSerialNumber;
    }

    // Bot parent number
    private int parentSerialNumber = SN.nextInt(rangeSerialNumber); // Sets the bot's parent number

    public int getParentSN() { // A getter for the bot's serial number
        return this.parentSerialNumber;
    }

    public void setNewBotSN(int botSerialNumber) {
        this.botSerialNumber = botSerialNumber;
    }
    
    // Bot constructor
    public Bot() {
        System.out.println("Bot serial number " + getSN());
        System.out.println("Bot parent number " + getParentSN());
        System.out.println();

    }
}

public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        int botCounter = 0;
        int botPopulation = 1000;

        // Loop
        while (botCounter < botPopulation) {
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1); // Delay
            Bot bot = new Bot(); // Creates new bot
            if (bot.getSN() == bot.originalSN) { // Main Code
                System.out.println("Bot found!");
                break;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Current bot serial number does not match");
                bot.setNewBotSN(bot.getParentSN()); // Changes the the serial number to parent number
                System.out.println("New bot serial number is " + bot.getSN());
                System.out.println();
                botCounter++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've been debugging since yesterday, I really want this program to work.
Thanks.